# Graphics card (RX 570) keeps crashing

Tags: crash, gpu, amd-radeon

Okay, so my graphics card has been crashing for quite a while now. My graphics card is an MSI Armor RX 570 8GB. My power supply is Thermaltake Smart BX1RGB 550W 80+ Bronze. So, when I would fire up almost any game, it would crash after playing a few minutes. The crash goes like this - there would be a blue/black/green/white screen - the color of the screen would vary, and the audio would get stuck for a few seconds, then one of two things would happen - the system would become unresponsive and I would have to force restart the PC again by holding down the power button (this happens most of the time) or it would restart on its own. After that if I fire up the same game again, the PC would crash again in the same manner and would become unresponsive and I would have to force restart again or would restart on its own. This cycle would continue for once or twice more and then the game would run smoothly without any crashing. Now say, after my gaming session is over (can go from an hour to up to 3 hours) and I turn on the computer again the next day, or say even after 3 or 6 hours. Then the entire crashing cycles would go on for another 3-4 times again and then I would be pretty much be able to continue gaming for pretty much as long as I want. I have tried monitoring the crashes with GPU-Z, but haven't noticed any unusual figures in the statistics. So, any idea why this is happening? And how to fix this? 
P.S. My current driver version is 20.4.2. I have noticed the same problem with previous 20 version drivers as well (which it came with). I bought the graphics card last December (2019, that is).

Comment: Can you borrow another graphics card to check if it would work as expected?

Comment: In this lockdown, unfortunately it is not possible. 

Comment: Okay, there is an update. So I tried doing a bunch of things like install pro drivers, uninstall drivers using DDU. I don't know what happened, after DDU, I could not boot up to Windows. Display driver corruption maybe? Anyway, at the end of it all, I did a System Repair on Windows, so Windows reinstalled and updated my Graphics Driver to 20.4.2. And now, I've noticed that when I run Unigine's Superposition benchmark, my PC doesn't crash. But it would crash once the benchmark is over, like after a minute or so. What could cause that? PSU issue?

Answer (score 0):

I also have same experience. after 3 days install and re-install, finally i've found the solution in the BIOS setting. I disable "ANTI SURGE SUPPORT", and thanks God, it never crash again what ever driver version installed.
I am using Asus Motherboard.

[image]